# User account mapping with SAML

Tags: saml, community-cloud

I'm developing an application that uses Salesforce as an identity provider (IdP). How would you implement the following:

> When user authenticates to Salesforce as the identity provider, the
>   ensuing Salesforce session + security context should be associated
>   with another user, not the user whose credentials were entered on the
>   login page. On the service provider side we need to see the user
>   identity whose credentials were entered on the login page.

The one who has to be logged in is identified by mapping on SP (my) side.

Comment: Even though the technical challenges as stated can be solved, this is an example of a [X-Y problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). If you add the details of what you're trying to achieve via an edit to your question (don't reply in comments), you'll see better answers.

Comment: @identigral corrected

Comment: You're still talking about a solution. The problem statement might be _we have 1 million users. How do we minimize the cost of salesforce licenses_. (This may not be the problem you're attempting to solve, it's just an example)

Comment: @identigral thanks for training me in asking questions) But I don't understand you. _How would you implement the following_ - isn't it a question?

Comment: It is a question and a valid one. It's also a XY problem: you're asking about your attempted solution rather than your actual problem. You are trying to solve problem X, and you think solution Y would work, but instead of asking about X when you run into trouble, you ask about Y.